# Why is this text moving when I increase my view window size?

Tags: html, css

I have the rest of my main body below a div containing my iframe video at the top. I've used an absolute unit for the iframe and div container.

I can't figure out why the text below my iframe is moving down the page when I widen my view window.

```css
    .vid-1  {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 56%;
      margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    }

    iframe  {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    @keyframes righttoleft {
      0%  {
        transform: translateX(100%);
      }
      100%  {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }

    @media only screen /* Tablet */

    .vid-1  {
      display: inline-block;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 1000px;
    }

    iframe  {
      width: 100%;
      height: 562px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<main>
          <div class="vid-1 lefttoright">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/momqQl-9-tg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <h1 class="text-style">Common Questions</h1>
          <div class="line"></div>

</main>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set paddings/margins with percentages (i.e. `padding-bottom: 56%;`), the percentage is relative to the element's width. So, when you set an element's width to 100% and widen the window, the element will get wider, increasing your bottom padding accordingly.

Try to use absolute units for the bottom padding, such as `padding-bottom: 50px`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: perfect! Thanks very much.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`padding-bottom: 56%;` this css is the cause of hiding your header text. give a constant padding.

```
.vid-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks very much.